# making an array from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, php-5.3

I'm going crazy with this issue, I want to get an array separated by commas(string) like example:(1,2,4,6) from a database and insert this as a variable inside a query like(select from table where id IN($variable string). Can anyone help me with this?

example:

```
<?php
//connect
$sql = "select id from users where id=1";
//get the results as an array
```

insert that variable inside this query

```
select from table where id IN($variable);
//
?>
```

i tried multiple ways and always have different issues. Please need an answer!

Comment: Could you add your code to the question? Why isn't it working?

Comment: What about *one* query that does this? `SELECT ... WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ...)` Or a `JOIN`? Also, `SELECT id WHERE id = 1`...? I can tell you the result without executing it: `1`.

Comment: implode the array to string separated by `,` ? :)

Answer (score 1):

`implode()`transforms an array into a string of values separated by the char you choose:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); // make an array
$list = implode(',',$arr);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN($list)";
```