# passing array to string not ok

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, php-5.3

i have this script and im having a problem passing this array to a string with commas.
i want it to be a string so i can insert it as a variable inside another query in the select...where... IN($variable);
i tried the implode and it dont echo the ids as a string it echoes Array.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
mysql_select_db("wall");

$sql = "select id from table where id=1";
$result = mysql_query( $sql);

$myArray='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $popurl = $row['id'];
    $myArray[] = $popurl;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: "I tried `implode`" -- where is that code?

Comment: Please don't repost the same question all the time... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469388/making-an-array-from-database

Comment: sorry for posting so many times, wont happen again

Comment: Please note that the `mysql` functions are **deprecated, and will be removed in future PHP versions**. Use `mysqli` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$myArray= array() ; //Here you must declare it as array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  $popurl = $row['id'];

  $myArray[] = $popurl;
}

$string = "'" . implode("', '", $myArray) . "'" ; 
//Will make ready string like 'data','data2', 'data3'
```